# cannot make authentication work

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, rest, spring-security

I am struggling for a few hours to create a small authentication system using Spring Security but I have not had luck yet.

What I want is a login form which goes through AngularJS to a database and searches with the provided data. For the purpose of making it work, I tried to use an in memory database.

Here is the code I used:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/authentication")
public class AuthenticationController {

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public Principal user(Principal user) {
        return user;
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
    protected static class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/login.html", "/lib/**", "/app/**", "/css/**", "/js/**").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
            http.formLogin().loginPage("/login.html").defaultSuccessUrl("/index.html")
                    .failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll();

            // Logout
            http.logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                    .permitAll();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
                throws Exception {
            // Authorization
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("p1")
                    .roles("USER");
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("root").password("p2")
                    .roles("USER", "ADMIN");
        }

        private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
            HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
            repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
            return repository;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the authenticate function from Angular:

```
    function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $location) {

        var authenticate = function(credentials, callback) {

            var headers = credentials ? {
                authorization : "Basic "
                        + btoa(credentials.username + ":"
                                + credentials.password)
            } : {};

            $http.get('authentication/user', {
                headers : headers
            }).success(function(data) {
                console.log(data.name);
                if (data.name) {
                    $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                } else {
                    $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                }
                callback && callback();
            }).error(function() {
                $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                callback && callback();
            });

        }

        authenticate();

        $scope.credentials = {};

        $scope.login = function() {
            authenticate($scope.credentials, function() {
                if ($rootScope.authenticated) {
                    $location.path("/index.html");
                    $scope.error = false;
                } else {
                    //$location.path("/login");
                    $scope.error = true;
                }
            });
        };
    });
```

Do you have any idea why this isn't working? The provided code I took from a few tutorials which are very similar. I tried a slightly different way previous to this which used `httpBasic` but still am not getting the desired result.

Any advice? Thank you!

Comment: *am not getting the desired result.* ... but what do you expect and what do you have ?

Comment: I expect to be redirected to `index.html` when I enter `user` and `p1`. Am I wrong with those expectations? From my understanding, it should put something in those headers when you are authenticated. It's the first time I use spring, I read a few things about authentication ways with Spring Security but still it's hard to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite late in my timezone and cannot test & execute your code :), but from my point of view you do not have a chance to run your code properly.

You are inappropriately mixing basic authentication with form login authentication. You declare form login:

```
http.formLogin().loginPage("/login.html").defaultSuccessUrl("/index.html")
                .failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll();
```

which briefly means that you require form login with POST to /login.html page.

Form login means that you should post a form using angular with username & password fields included (as if you posted a normal form using POST method). Therefore you should have something like this in authenticate function:

```
var authenticate = function(credentials, callback) {

        $http.post('login.html', {username: username, password: password} ).success(function(data) {
            // do something
        }).error(function() {
            // do something
        });
    }
```

Just please be forgiving if something does not compile above because I simply cannot test it/verify it.